# Affine Kac-Moody Group Isometry of a Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, riemannian-geometry, loop-spaces

An isometry of a Riemannian manifold is an infinitesimal displacement generated by a Killing vector field $V=\zeta^aV_a=\zeta^aV_a^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$. If the isometry corresponds to the action of a Lie group $G$ on the manifold, then $V_a$ gives rise to the corresponding Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, i.e.,

$[V_a,V_b]^i=-if_{ab}^{c}V_c^i$

(To be precise, we have an antihomomorphism from the Lie algebra to the relevant Killing vector fields, hence the negative sign on the RHS.)

My question is whether there exist manifolds with affine Kac-Moody group symmetry, with the relevant Killing vector fields giving rise to an affine Kac-Moody algebra:

$[V_{an},V_{bm}]^i=-if_{ab}^{c}V_{c(m+n)}^i-c^i(x)m\delta_{m+n,0}\delta_{ab}$

Here, $c(x)$ is a vector field which represents the central element of the affine algebra.

If there are such manifolds, what functional form would the Killing vector fields have?

Comment: I am no expert. I would try first (as the manifolds) the Lie groups corresponding to affine Kac-Moody algebras. A google search returned that such groups are centrally extended loop groups of Lie groups $G$. If $G$ is compact, I would try out the induced metric on the centrally extended loop group of $G$ by a bi-invariant metric on $G$. Again, I am no expert. This is just a suggestion.

Comment: The isometry group of a (finite dimensional) Riemannian  manifold is always a Lie group.